# How to include "itemCondition" and "logo" schema tags in the schema.org product snippets?

Tags: html, schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm trying to add schema.org snippets to my products page. My client requested me to  display following schema.org tags in the products single page

1) itemCondition

2) logo (display only the brand image URL)

Schema.org gives only the tags description for each tags but haven't mentioned how it's should to be implement for most tags. Currently my snippet display as follows

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <img itemprop="image" src="/uploads/pen102-a13-olv_1.jpg" />
    <span itemprop="name">BOWERBRIDGE INSULATED JKT</span>


    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer">
      <span itemprop="lowPrice">$400</span>
        to <span itemprop="highPrice">$600</span>
        from <span itemprop="offerCount">20</span> sellers
    </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone please let me know how can I include the my client required tags to above snippet.

My client required following schema.org tags.

1) itemCondition

2) logo (display only the brand image URL)

EDIT

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <meta itemprop='logo' content='http://rstest.mydomain.com/images/userfiles/logos/stone-island.png'/>

    <span itemprop='itemCondition'><br />
        • Removable arm badge logo<br />
        • Pull over hoddy<br />
        • Panel pocket<br />
        • Regular fit<br />
        • Zip side pockets<br />
        • Long sleeve<br />
        • 100% Cotton<br />
        • 40 Degree wash<br />
        <br />
        591565220<br />
        <br />
        View our full range of <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/mens/hoodies/" target="_self">Mens Hoodies</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Audience code**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="audience" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PeopleAudience">
    <meta itemprop="gender" content="male"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Error: Page contains property "gender" which is not part of the schema.**

Comment: I'm trying this according to the Schema.org specification for other tags but for this I'm not sure. However, I'm waiting client confirmation to try @Devnook instruction. If you've a suggestion please let me know.

Comment: But why don’t you show us how you would implement `itemCondition` and `logo`? Did you try a validator and it showed errors? If so, then show us your code and quote the error.

Comment: I'll will, my client having some trouble with his server. I'll post the attempted code as soon as I got the access. Until that could you pls hold on.

Comment: Hi, I tried @Devnook example and working great (see my above edit for tried code)! but I found another issue I thought you could help. I need to add `audience` tag and when I do as per the other codes it's displaying the "Error: Page contains property 'gender' which is not part of the schema." message in the Google snippet tool. See my above attempted `Audience code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `logo`: Instead of the `meta` element you [should use the `link` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669):

```
<link itemprop="logo" href="http://rstest.mydomain.com/images/userfiles/logos/stone-island.png" />
```

For `itemCondition`: You should not use [`br` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) here. Use a `ul` for the features, `div` for the article number, and `p` for the "View our full range …".

For `audience`: [`PeopleAudience`](http://schema.org/PeopleAudience) doesn’t support the [`gender` property](http://schema.org/gender) (it’s for `People` only). You probably mean the [`suggestedGender` property](http://schema.org/suggestedGender).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Structured Data Helper to do the tagging for you (at least for logo):

https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/u/0/

If you play around with other properties similar to itemCondition, you can get idea of how the markup should look like.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="http://example.com"/>
  <meta itemprop="url"  content="http://example.com/myurl"/>
  <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com/logo.png"/>
  </div>
</span>
```