# Schema.org "gender" itemprop failed validate in the Google Rich snippet tool

Tags: schema.org

When I include the "gender" itemprop attribute inside the audience tag and validate with the [Google snippet tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), it displays the following message:

> **Error: Page contains property "gender" which is not part of the schema.**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
 …
 <meta itemprop="url" content="http://ww.mydomain.com/polo-ralph-lauren/shirts/white/pinpoint-oxford-ls-shirt/rlp039-a13-wht/" />
 <meta itemprop='productID' content='rlp039-a13-wht'/>
 <meta itemprop='logo' content='http://ww.mydomain.com/images/userfiles/logos/polo-ralph-lauren.png'/>
 <span itemprop="audience" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PeopleAudience">
  <meta itemprop="gender" content="male"/>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems correct. What's your question?

Comment: Question is when I validate this snippet it Google snippet tool throw following error 'Error: Page contains property "gender" which is not part of the schema.'

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error message is because the gender property is part of the person schema, not a part of the people audience schema.  But to make your markup work, change gender to suggestedGender.  It should test fine then.

Answer (score 0):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19787456/1591669), [`PeopleAudience`](http://schema.org/PeopleAudience) doesn’t support the [`gender` property](http://schema.org/gender).

You probably want the [`suggestedGender` property](http://schema.org/suggestedGender).